# How Can I Make List Items "Tabbable" (Use Tab Key To :focus On Them)

Tags: html

How can I make List Items tabbable? (meaning: using the `TAB` key to `:focus` on them). I need to know for Handicap Accessibility purposes.

I added 2 text fields to give a reference point to `TAB` from; if you tab from the `textarea` it goes to the next one, then skips over all the list items.

**HTML:**

```
<textarea></textarea>
<textarea></textarea>
<ul>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ul>
```

**CSS:**

```
li {
  display: block;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 95%;
}
a:active, a:focus,
li:active, li:focus {border: 5px solid orange}

li:nth-of-type(1) {background-color: red}
li:nth-of-type(2) {background-color: yellow}
li:nth-of-type(3) {background-color: blue}
li:nth-of-type(4) {background-color: green}
```

**jsFiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/h815zLnp/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the tabindex attribute - generally its used only for navigating around inputs in forms and so forth - but it can be used to determine the order of focus to any HTML element. I have used your existing text areas and li's and if you start in the first text area and use the tab key - you will be able to see the focus change to the funky order I have listed in the tabindex codes. Also shift-tab moves through the items in reverse tab index order:

```css
li {
  display: block;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 95%;
}

a:active, a:focus,
li:active, li:focus {border: 5px solid orange}

li:nth-of-type(1) {background-color: red}
li:nth-of-type(2) {background-color: yellow}
li:nth-of-type(3) {background-color: blue}
li:nth-of-type(4) {background-color: green}
```

```html
<textarea  tabindex="1"></textarea>
<textarea  tabindex="3"></textarea>
<ul>
  <li tabindex="2"></li>
  <li tabindex="5"></li>
  <li tabindex="4"></li>
  <li tabindex="6"></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Would this require me to add `tabindex` throughout the whole page? And is there a way that I can get `tabindex` to follow the natural flow of the page?

Comment: Just found out that you can! Explanation here: http://webaim.org/techniques/keyboard/tabindex if you want to add it to your answer

Comment: happy to help - but its probably better to structure your page elements in an appropriate flow rather than relying on tab index.

Comment: Yeah, that's what my comment was for! `tabindex="0"` makes an element "tabbable" without affecting page flow

Comment: https://codepen.io/escapedcat/pen/eeMYPG here's a comparison of using links (with and without href) and tabindex. Just as an addition to this.

Comment: thanks @escapedcat - interesting - I guess I never consider using links without href...to me a link with no href is really not a link and is more akin to a 'span' or even a 'p' that displays the contained text.  I am also not sure that an 'a' element without a href is valid html (maybe thats changed). It certainly works in terms of tabbing order, but I would not use it.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to accomplish this is to use `<li tabindex="0">` with a JavaScript function to add keyboard behaviors for in-focus elements.

`tabindex="0"` will make sure that the tabs are accessed in the natural flow order. A solid JavaScript solution accounting for both `enter` and `space` keys is available here:
https://karlgroves.com/2014/11/24/ridiculously-easy-trick-for-keyboard-accessibility